# confusion regarding range of char

Tags: c, binary, char, range, twos-complement

As we know that the range of char is `-128` to `127`.

The 2's compliment of `-128` and the binary of `128` is same, which is

> 10000000

So why the range of char is `-128` to `127` but not `-127` to `128` .
Where as in case of `int` , `128` and `-128` both are different.

Comment: The range of char is not always -128 to 127. Even if you discount the part of the C standard that says that it has 8 _or more_ bits, it can be signed or unsigned. Perhaps you meant `int8_t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In twos-complement notation, whenever the high-order bit is 1, the number is negative. So the biggest positive number is

```
01111111 = 127
```

and the smallest negative number is

```
10000000 = -128
```

The same thing happens for `int`, but its range is much larger. The biggest positive int is

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = 2147483647
```

and the smallest negative int is

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 = -2147483648
```

As you can see, in both cases, the smallest negative is 1 more than the biggest positive.

You might be wondering, **If there are the same number of bits other than the sign bit, why are there more negative numbers than positives?** That's because you're not counting `0`. It has 0 in the high-order bit, so it's considered positive in this notation. When you include that, there are 128 negative chars, and 128 non-negative chars, and they balance equally.

Comment: take for example `4294967234`, its binary is `11111111111111111111111111000010`.Its high order bit is `1` , so how it is positive?

Comment: That's an unsigned int, we're talking about signed int.

Comment: or it's a `long long`, which is 64 bits.

Comment: it is a unsigned it, so is the theory of high order bit is not applicable on unsigned int

Comment: @zee yes, unsigned int as the name implies you can't have negative numbers in this variable. so you have all the 32bits(if its a 32bit variable) to represent a positive number. if you need to represent negative numbers, the computer needs to know if its negative, this is done by setting the sign bit to 1 and using 2's compliment.

Answer (score 0):

A character has 8 bits. So the bit pattern for -128 and 128 are the same when you have 8 bits to deal with. (ignoring the sign bit)

Now the int. It has more bits so the MSB is not -128 but a larger -ve number depending on the platform.

It does exhibit the same problem at a "higher" number

Answer (score 0):

Look 128 is

```
10000000
```

But by default char is signed compiler treats first bit as sign bit and treats the no. 
as negative and calculates its 2s complement ( because MSB is 1)

```
2s complement is
 01111111
      +        1
 10000000
```

So - 128 is stored
To store +128  compiler have to consider 9 bits that is to interpret

```
010000000
```

Here MSB is 0 for positive no. But size is of 9 bits this shows why char only accomodate upto +127 and if we want to store +128 then -128 will be stored as explained above